# Decrypt function is not working c#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to write an 'enrypt-decrypt' program and I have some problems with the decrypt function.

Somehow I can't save the stream reader "ReadToEnd()" into my empty string called "text".

I found the function arround the internet, and I tried to solve it by changing the variable name and by using "IDisposed" instead of "using". I couldn't solve it.

```
static string Decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    string text = String.Empty;
    // Create an Aes object
    // with the specified key and IV.
    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = Key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for decryption.
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {

               using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(cs) )
               {
                   // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting 
                    stream

                // and place them in a string.
                    text = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }
        }
    }
   return text;
}
```

The text string is only defined in this function, the error comes in the line:

text = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();

And it says:

> Crypt.cs(145,29): error CS0136: A local variable named 'text' cannot
>   be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to
>   'text', which is already used in a `parent or current' scope to denote
>   something else Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

Comment: What line is the error on? also post code as **actual code**, not images. Though if I had to take a guess, where you have `string text = String.Empty();`, you probably already have a variable named `text` in your class.

Comment: There is a bit missing in your code after 'stream' but it would be a lot easier if you were to post your code (as text) to StackOverflow rather than a link to a bitmap.

Comment: I want to know why *so many people* prefer posting pictures of their code and errors instead of the code and error text itself.  Maybe this is a meta topic...but WHY does it happen so often?

Comment: @rory.ap I want to know why they initial post links instead of embedding the images.

Comment: @rory.ap probably because it's easier to post a screenshot than to copy paste code and format it so it looks nice. I agree it's very annoying and lazy to just post screenshots though.

Comment: @juharr -- new users dont' have permission to paste pictures I think.

Comment: @Bas -- Taking a screen shot, saving it to your computer, pasting it to that imagr site, and including it is easier than copy/paste text??  Why not take a pic with your phone, email it to yourself, download it, print it out, scan it back in, save it and then post it?

Comment: @rory.ap You can easily paste a image from your clipboard into imgur. But don't mistake it, I totally agree with you. It's lazy and annoying.

Comment: @rory.ap It's been a long time since I was new, but I don't think that posting an image is restricted, at least it's not listed on the privileges page.

Comment: "and I tried to solve it, but I couldn't." No offense, but this is a completely useless sentence to us as potential answerers.  Tell us ***what*** you attempted, ***why*** it didn't work.  Just more detail in general.  Pretend we have no context into your problem, because we don't.

Comment: It's been almost 20 minutes and you still haven't told us what line the error is happening on.  Also, where is the error message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you miss some code here, cause that is not valid:

```
// Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting 
stream
```

Comment: What do you think I should add after this? I didn't miss code pasting it here, it's just like mine

Comment: Try removing this line, your code should then be compiled.